# How do I "cancel" an error in gremlin-console and continue with the next command without exiting?

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

In `gremlin-console`, when I make a syntax error like the example below - where I forgot to the 2nd quotation - I don't know what to type to return me back to the normal prompt `gremlin>`. Anything I type including `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+U` will continue the `......2>` like below.

```
gremlin> g.V("
......1>
......1> "
......2> )
groovysh_parse: 1: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 1, column 6.
   g.V("
        ^

1 error
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]n
......2>
```

How do I "cancel" an error and continue with gremlin-console without exiting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `:clear` or `:c` which erases any buffer built up in the console memory of the previous command. Use `:?` to get more information on other commands that you might be helpful. Also, consider reading the [The Gremlin Console](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/) tutorial for more tips on console usage.

Comment: Thanks! I'd say though the description in `:h` wasn't very descriptive.

Comment: Gremlin Console is built on the Groovy console so I guess it inherited that particular description - true enough though.